# Jetty set resource base

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

I am trying to set resource base in a Jetty server and I am getting a null pointer exception

Code

```
Server JETTY_SERVER = new Server(9991);
final WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
context.setResourceBase(<PATH>);
context.setContextPath("/");
context.setParentLoaderPriority(true);

JETTY_SERVER.setHandler(context);
JETTY_SERVER.start();
```

Exception

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.sendData(DefaultServlet.java:792)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:513)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:669)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:578)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1072)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:382)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1006)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:276)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:103)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet.doGet(DefaultServlet.java:566)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:669)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:560)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1072)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:382)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1006)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:365)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:485)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:926)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:988)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:635)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:628)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
>       at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Any help would be appreciated...

Thanks

Comment: What version of Jetty?  What version of Java?  What does the debug logging show?

Comment: jetty 8.1.8.v20121106, JDK-1_6_0_27